# How can I use icons on a my own maptiles klokantech docker container?

Tags: icon, mapbox-gl, docker

If I take this example:

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-markers/

an change the mapsource from:

```
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9'
```

to my own docker container:

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: "map",
    style: "http://localhost:8080/styles/osm-bright/style.json",
    center: [11.7357, 48.8],
    zoom: 8
});

map.on("load", function() {
    map.addLayer({
        id: "points",
        type: "symbol",
        source: {
            type: "geojson",
            data: {
                type: "FeatureCollection",
                features: [
                    {
                        type: "Feature",
                        geometry: {
                            type: "Point",
                            coordinates: [11, 49]
                        },
                        properties: {
                            title: "Mapbox DC",
                            icon: "monument"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        type: "Feature",
                        geometry: {
                            type: "Point",
                            coordinates: [11, 50]
                        },
                        properties: {
                            title: "Mapbox SF",
                            icon: "harbor"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        layout: {
            "icon-image": "{icon}-15",
            "text-field": "{title}",
            "text-font": ["Open Sans Semibold", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
            "text-offset": [0, 0.6],
            "text-anchor": "top"
        }
    });
});
```

Then disapear the icons on map. How can I use icons on my own container?

I use mapbox-gl-js/v0.41.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use own marker follow the tutorial:

https://www.mapbox.com/help/custom-markers-gl-js/#final-product

The icon PNG is in the same directory as the index.html. That's all - see turorial.